# Calculating a point in 3D using the Pythagorean theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to calculate **Az**  If I'm just given **Ax** and **Ay**.
As an example say **Ax** is **3.4** and **Ay** is **7.8** how can I go about finding **Az**?

If your wondering I was watching a video [Link to SLERP video](https://youtu.be/BXajpAy5-UI?t=540) and I wanted to ask the above question about it because I couldn't find an answer to it.

See formula below:
[image: Pythagorean theorem image]

Comment: Do you know the length of $\mathbf A$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner unfortunately no just Ax and Ay.

Comment: Then it's not possible, per the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four unknown terms in the equation $||\vec A|| = \sqrt{A_x^2 + A_y^2 + A^z_2}$, namely: $||\vec A||$, $A_x$, $A_y$, and $A_z$. So if you know three of them, you can solve for the fourth.

But knowing only two of them, such as $A_x$ and $A_y$, it's not possible to solve for either of the other ones such as $A_z$.

The best you can do is to solve algebraically for $$A_z = \sqrt{||\vec A|| - A_x^2 - A_y^2}$$ but as you can see from that equation, you have to know the values of all three of $||\vec A||$, $A_x$, and $A_y$ in order to compute a value of $A_z$.